# jQuery get div content text and elements except some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the contents of a div (text, paragraphs, etc) excepting the divs with a certain data attribute then storing it to a data variable.

I've tried:

```
 var $content = $(this).contents().not('[data-value]');
 var $data = $content.prop("innerHTML");

 alert($data);
```

However, I get $data as undefined.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: How about `$content.html()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do:

```
var el = $(this).clone();
var data = $('[data-value]', el).remove();
alert(data.html());
```